# Getting crash while adding a new node in firebase using swift 3

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am adding a new node in firebase using firebase server timestamp as node name. It's crashing and giving this error "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'InvalidPathValidation', reason: '(child:) Must be a non-empty string and not contain '.' '#' '$' '[' or ']'' ". Here is my code

```
  let kFirebaseServerValueTimestamp = [".sv":"timestamp"]
            let serverTimestamp = "sosLog" + String(describing: kFirebaseServerValueTimestamp)
            FIRDatabase.database().reference().child(serverTimestamp).setValue(["residentUid":self.user_uid,"name":self.user_name, "timestamp": [".sv": "timestamp"], "status": "SOS" ]){

  }
```

Here is my db struct. So I want to create a node name sosLog1234567456 just like admin, billingdate node.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oh9Rw.png)

Answer (score 0):

Firebase has some keys restrictions. Create your owns keys that are compliant to below rules.

> If you create your own keys, they must be UTF-8 encoded, can be a
>   maximum of 768 bytes, and cannot contain ., $, #, [, ], /, or ASCII
>   control characters 0-31 or 127.

Comment: I got your point but i am not getting what is wrong in my code?